# Reading back a custom dataset TFRecords

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, tfrecord

I am trying to create a custom dataset in `TFRecords` for a CycleGAN model. The model requires a new type of dataset which is not available so I need to create one. I have a few JPG images of 256x256. Following [this](https://www.kaggle.com/gpreda/convert-jpg-images-to-tfrecords) link, I created TFrecords file for my images, below code:

```
def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

# images input
def convert_to(images, output_directory, name):
    num_examples = images.shape[0]
    rows = images.shape[1]
    cols = images.shape[2]
    depth = 1

    filename = os.path.join(output_directory, name + '.tfrecords')
    print('Writing', filename)
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename)
    for index in range(num_examples):
        image = images[index]
        image_raw = images[index].tobytes()
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
            'height': _int64_feature(rows),
            'width': _int64_feature(cols),
            'depth': _int64_feature(depth),
            'image_raw': _bytes_feature(image_raw)}))
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

def read_image(file_name, images_path):
    image = skimage.io.imread(images_path + file_name)
    return image

def get_name(img_name):
    remove_ext = img_name.split(".")[0]
    name = remove_ext.split("_")
    return name[0]

images_path = "data/train/"
image_list = os.listdir(images_path)
images = []
for img_name in tqdm(image_list):
    tfrec_name = get_name(img_name)
    print(tfrec_name)
    img_data = read_image(img_name, images_path)
    convert_to(img_data, "data/cat_image_tfrecords", tfrec_name+"_cat_image")
```

Once the TFRecords are written, I use below code to read and decode it back

```
PHOTO_FILENAMES = tf.io.gfile.glob(str('data/cat_image_tfrecords/*.tfrecords'))

IMAGE_SIZE = [256, 256]

def decode_image(image):
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = (tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 127.5) - 1
    image = tf.reshape(image, [*IMAGE_SIZE, 3])
    return image

def read_tfrecord(example):
    tfrecord_format = {
    'height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'depth': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image_raw': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    }
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, tfrecord_format)
    image = decode_image(example['image_raw'])
    return image

def load_dataset(filenames, labeled=True, ordered=False):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
    dataset = dataset.map(read_tfrecord, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset

photo_ds = load_dataset(PHOTO_FILENAMES, labeled=False).batch(1)
example_photo = next(iter(photo_ds))
```

The decoding does not work since I get the below error in the last line

```
InvalidArgumentError: Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with ']LBhXKeQFVC4S=/1'
     [[{{node DecodeJpeg}}]]
```

Clearly there is a mismatch between how I am writing the TFRecord in `convert_to` function and how I am reading it back in `read_tfrecord` function. But I am not sure how to fix it. Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

@sebastian-sz solution solves the problem. I tried to display one image like below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplot(121)
plt.title('Photo')
plt.imshow(example_photo[0])
```

It displays the image but I see that the color/light of the image is much darker than the original image. Not sure what is going on though. Attached screenshot. Original image at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: What's your Tensorflow version? Im trying to reproduce the code but I get `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python_io'` on Tensorflow 2.7.0

Comment: Tensorflow 2.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues in your code:

#### Parameter Issue:

The problem is in a function `convert_to`, in more detail, the function expects a list of images:

```py
(...)
image = images[index]
(...)
```

However, you are passing a single image
`convert_to(img_data, "data/cat_image_tfrecords", tfrec_name+"_cat_image")`
Hence, later the `image` is of shape (for example) `224, 3` which is an invalid image shape.

To fix this, change `convert_to` to accept a single image.

#### Serialization Issue

Skimage `.tobytes` seems to be incompatible. Consider using `tf.io.encode_jpeg(image).numpy()` to obtain image bytes.

#### Full code

I was able to save and read sample image with the following code:

```py
# Saving
def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

# images input
def convert_to(image, output_directory, name):
    rows = image.shape[0]
    cols = image.shape[1]
    depth = 1

    filename = os.path.join(output_directory, name + '.tfrecords')
    print('Writing', filename)
    writer = tf.compat.v1.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename)
    print(image.shape)
    image_raw = tf.io.encode_jpeg(image).numpy()
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'height': _int64_feature(rows),
        'width': _int64_feature(cols),
        'depth': _int64_feature(depth),
        'image_raw': _bytes_feature(image_raw)}))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

def read_image(file_name, images_path):
    image = skimage.io.imread(images_path + file_name)
    return image

def get_name(img_name):
    remove_ext = img_name.split(".")[0]
    name = remove_ext.split("_")
    return name[0]

images_path = "data/train/"
image_list = os.listdir(images_path)
for img_name in tqdm(image_list):
    tfrec_name = get_name(img_name)
    print(tfrec_name)
    img_data = read_image(img_name, images_path)
    convert_to(img_data, "data/cat_image_tfrecords", tfrec_name+"_cat_image")


# Loading:
PHOTO_FILENAMES = tf.io.gfile.glob(str('data/cat_image_tfrecords/*.tfrecords'))

IMAGE_SIZE = [256, 256]

def decode_image(image):
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = (tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 127.5) - 1
    # Changed this from reshape 
    # Consider reshape if all your images have the same shape
    image = tf.image.resize(image, IMAGE_SIZE)
    return image

def read_tfrecord(example):
    tfrecord_format = {
    'height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'depth': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image_raw': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    }
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, tfrecord_format)
    image = decode_image(example['image_raw'])
    return image

def load_dataset(filenames, labeled=True, ordered=False):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
    dataset = dataset.map(read_tfrecord, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset

photo_ds = load_dataset(PHOTO_FILENAMES, labeled=False).batch(1)
example_photo = next(iter(photo_ds))
```

Comment: I see, can you share an updated code?

Comment: Added working code.

Comment: the solution works!. Please check the EDIT on the main post. I tried to display the image back and I see a difference in color/lighting wrt the original image.

Comment: It's probably because you rescale values when loading `image = (tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 127.5) - 1`. If you comment this line, the image should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the `read_tfrecord` function like below, see the commented out line and that solves this particular error.

```
def read_tfrecord(example):
    tfrecord_format = {
    'height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'depth': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image_raw': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    }
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, tfrecord_format)
    #image = decode_image(example['image_raw'])
    image = tf.io.decode_raw(example['image_raw'], tf.float32)
    return image
```